# I need help viewing videos!

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services

How does one view videos on Tor if it will not allow Flash?  Is there another way?  I have tried several sites, and I am not able to view any videos.  What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's very site-dependent, but there are two ways, generally:

- If you're using Tor Browser Bundle - use a HTML5 player on the site, it's ubiquitous now.
- If you have just Tor(tor Expert bundle) - use it as a router or a proxy for VM's where you do launch a flash-supporting browser to prevent data leaks. It's also the only way if you have just flash player on the website